# Input shape for keras LSTM in Tensorflow? Error: got list of 8 arrays, expected 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to pass data through an LSTM, at this point just the most basic architecture to get it up and running. My input x shape is (8,200,6,2) and y is (8,200,2). So I have a list of 8 arrays containing sequences of 200 where each element is an array with shape (6,2).

Edit: Now flattened (6,2) arrays to (12) so shape is (8,200,12) and (8,200,2)

I have tried following `batch_input_shape = (batch_size, timesteps, seq_len)` but every combination gives me and error when I try to run epochs. The error is:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays 
that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. 
Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 8 
arrays: [array([[[0.45715529, 0.66666669]
```

What should my input size actually be and how can I fix this error to get it running?

I am keeping my model at the bare minimum to begin with:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 12), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

history=model.fit(X_list, y_list,
                 epochs=50, batch_size=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

LSTM inputs shape in Keras must be in 3D. I suppose you can flatten your (6, 2) array to (12, ) and therefore have (8, 200, 12). I don't know what is your data but flattening will not affect performance of the network.

Your input must be `(n_of_batches, timesteps, samples)`. You can define it with the argument `input_shape` where you only need to put `(timesteps, samples)`. The layer will automatically detect the number of batches, this allows you to have a more dynamic architecture. However, if you want a more static option, you can define your input with the optional argument `batch_input_shape=(n_of_batches, timesteps, samples)`.

Also the flag `return_sequences=True` must be set to `True` if you have another LSTM layer after. Otherwise, set it to `False`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The (6,2) shape represents the x and y positions for 6 individual objects so would this be ok to flatten or would it lose its meaning? Also when I used input_shape with 2 arguments I got an error when compiling the model about the dimensions being wrong

Comment: The network doesn't know that it is looking at X and Y positions anyway. So it will not loose its meaning. Can you be more specific about this error ? Can you give the line where you call the function ?

Comment: The other error was my mistake, I had gotten confused. I flattened the input but now my input/output shapes are different as input = ((8, 200, 12), output =(8, 200, 2)). However I still get the same error as the original question with the LSTM like:: model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 12), return_sequences=True)) and then the running command as history=model.fit(X_list, y_list,
                 epochs=50, batch_size=n) and I can type any number for n and it still gives the same error

Comment: May seem obvious but are you sure that you have a (8, 200, 12) array and not a list of 8 array of shape (200, 12). Try to print input.shape. Otherwise, can you provide some more code of yours to better understand the problem ?

Comment: Nothing is obvious to me, apologies for my ignorance. This is my first time dealing with an LSTM. I'm pretty sure it's a list of 8 arrays. I have printed it out: np.shape(X_list), np.shape(y_list), type(X_list), type(X_list[0]), type(X_list[0][0]) ((8, 200, 12), (8, 200, 2), list, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray)

Comment: I'll edit my question and add some more of the code, I had to do a whole load of preprocessing to the raw data so I won't include that

Comment: Don't be sorry it is really ok ! I struggled for hours too the first time I used it. From what you put, try to set `return_sequences` to `False`. If it doesn't work could you please give the output of model.summary() ?

Comment: return seq to false still give me the error. Summary:                                                             
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_19 (LSTM)               (None, 128)               72192     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 258       
=================================================================
Total params: 72,450
Trainable params: 72,450
Non-trainable params: 0